# CSS Banner carousel/slider not working

Tags: css, slider, carousel, banner

I have the following css:

```
.banner {
    background: url(../images/banner4.jpg)  no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I would like to display other images as well, in a slider way.
I have tried some suggestions but nothing seems to work.

I am still new to CSS, so i would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may check out this page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work!